# Inputs with border responsive failure

Tags: html, css

I want to create a new form with inputs. The 2 first inputs should be 50% so they are next to each other and the rest 100%. The boxes are next to each other at width 49% but on mobile screens, they stack under each other.

I added a [**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/of1fL7bv/) to demonstrate my problem.

```
<input class="inputstyle" NAME="name" placeholder="Name" style="width:50%;border:2px solid #000;" value="name">
<input class="inputstyle" NAME="lastname" placeholder="Last name" style="width:50%;border:2px solid #000;" value="lastname">
<input class="inputstyle" NAME="birthplace" placeholder="Birthplace" style="width:100%;border:2px solid #000;" value="birthplace">
```

And at 50% on computers it doesnt equal the 100% input

I'm grateful for any help!

Comment: Or use 45%, take a look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/of1fL7bv/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need as well to mind borders and padding eventually. [`box-sizing:border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) will be usefull for this

https://jsfiddle.net/of1fL7bv/2/

Comment: Worked great! thank you man, does this box-sizing:border-box; work for all browsers?

Comment: @J.Doe take a look here to know where it works ;) http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can make use of CSS `calc()` function to subtract the border size from the total width like this:

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/8q0fw56m/)

```css
.inputstyle {
  /* full width */
  width:calc(100% - 4px); /* 4px because 2px border left + 2px border right */
  margin-top:1%;height:30px;background-color:#FFF;float:left;
  border:2px solid #000;
}
.half-width {
  /* half width */
  width:calc(50% - 4px);
}
```

```html
<input class="inputstyle half-width" NAME="name" placeholder="Name" value="name">
<input class="inputstyle half-width" NAME="lastname" placeholder="Last name" value="lastname">
<input class="inputstyle" NAME="birthplace" placeholder="Birthplace" value="birthplace">
```

Comment: Worked man, thank you. But the answer above was more simple, so I will go with it. But I appreciate the comment, though :)

Comment: You welcome @J.Doe, the other example is better not because it is more simple, both are simple but mainly because `box-sizing:border-box` has better browser suppert http://caniuse.com/#search=box-siz, than CSS `calc()` function http://caniuse.com/#search=calc.. this why I started my answer with "Alternatively"